# Safari's developer tools logs me out from signed sites

Tags: macos, safari

Whenever I open macOS Safari's web developer tool, such as the web inspector; the next I visit a page that needs log in (e.g. GMail) it requieres me to sign in again. Usually when I log in a site I select the option to keep me logged in next time I visit.

In Google Chrome's developer tools this does not happen. Is there any option to disable this behavior? I cannot find it in Safari's menu.

I am using macOS Sonoma 14.1.2.

Thank you!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this one?

Comment: No. :( Still I cannot find a setting to disable this behavior.